# Memory Leak Java OutOfMemoryError in Vector List

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, vector, memory-leaks

I am running a multithreaded application with 3 threads:

- Main Thread - Vector List to store Objects
- AdderThread -  Add Objects to this Vector List
- RemoverThread - Remove Objects with vectorList.clear() method (synchronized)

Application runs fine but after few hours it gives OutOfMemoryError.

I generated Heap dump and analysed with eclipse MAT which shows vectorList class taking all the memory.

Does `clear` method free memory which was occupied by individual objects ?

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure your `remove` method is called? Can you add a log printing the size of the vector before the `remove` method returns to check that the vector is empty?

Comment: Yes after clear() is called it prints Size as 0 . I am even using System.gc(); statement in a loop with 3 seconds sleep  still it gives the same error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are adding tasks faster than you are freeing them, you will get an OutOfMemoryError as your Vector will grow to the limit of your memory.

Instead of using a Vector for a work queue, I suggest using a BlockingQueue from the concurrency libraries.

e.g.

```
BlockingQueue<Work> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(MAX_TASKS_WAITING);

AdderThread calls queue.put(work); // blocks if the queue is full

RemoverThread call queue.take(); // blocks if there is nothing to do.
```

In fact it would be much simpler to use an ExecutorService as this combines a work queue with a thread pool. You submit tasks to the executor and it processes them. This avoids the need to write any code for the RemoverThread as such.

Comment: Thanks will try implementing with BlockingQueue . But doesnt the clear() method also delete the memory occupied by individual objects.
Each Individual Object has 2 hashmaps. I take the whole list of objects & copy in tempList->vectorList.clear()->process tempList

Comment: If you are removing correctly, you shouldn't need to call clear(). Only call clear if you want to discard some tasks. e.g. because you can't control the length of the waiting tasks.  Using a queue, you should never get so desperate.

Comment: clear() removes all the elements from the backing array. But the array itself is left untouched. If it grows very large, the empty array could be the cause of your OOM. An array can have up to 2^31 -1 elements. On a 32-bit JVM, that represents 8GB.

Comment: Using a bounded collection would avoid this issue. ;)